# Magento - with taxes?

Tags: php, magento

We are using Magento with a multistore structure and we want to open i UK. I made a UK tax rule and added it for a product, but for some reason it adds the tax to the given price even though i set it to be included. So the price actually contains tax from two different countries.

Anybody else tried this? Is this an error from the code or am i doing something wrong in Magento backend? Hope someone can help me to find a solution for this problem. My main store isnt the UK one, but a danish.

Comment: Figured out so it doesnt show double tax on single product page, but when i go to checkout it still shows the price with double tax?

Comment: Its probably only a settings who need to be removed or something but really cant figure out the issue.

Comment: Nobody ever had this experience?